# How to compile Saurik's ldid on Ubuntu?

Tags: gcc

I am trying to install Theos on my Ubuntu and I am stuck on step which is supposed to install ldid:

```
git clone git://git.saurik.com/ldid.git
cd ldid
git submodule update --init
./make.sh
```

When I execute make.sh I get following error:

```
root@ubuntu:~/ldid# ./make.sh 
+ g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o ldid ldid.cpp -I. -x c lookup2.c sha1.c 
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’ g++:
error: i386: No such file or directory g++: error: unrecognized
command line option ‘-arch’ g++: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
```

This is my gcc:

```
g++ -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
--with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

What am I missing? I am following [this](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#On_Mac_OS_X_or_Linux) tutorial and it doesn't mention any dependencies.